# Jest sees test suites but silently ignores the tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs2, jestjs, nuxt.js

The question refers to Jest testing in a Nuxt/Vue v2 project. The unit tests ran as expected, either passing or not passing. After some changes Jest stopped running the tests I had (neither passing nor failing).

```
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 0 of 10 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.454 s, estimated 10 s
Ran all test suites.
```

I removed some code that I didn’t need, I stashed the changes and tried again, but none of test suits were running. I checked-out to the project version, where the tests previously ran as expected. Still nothing.

I can even make an empty test suite and the runner won’t raise ‘your test suite must contain at least one test’ exception. This involves the tests in both `tests/unit` directory and in other folders.

I’m usually pretty methodical with regard to my commits, but maybe I messed something up. I cannot exclude a possibility that I mixed something in the dependency tree, e.g. by not adding some crucial dependency to package.json (I removed node_modules and installed it from scratch at some point). Maybe there is a dependency mismatch, which didn’t occur before…

What could be the issue? How to troubleshoot such case? I used Mocha/Chai before so I’m new to Jest.

Here are my settings:

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1",
    "^~/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1",
    "^vue$": "vue/dist/vue.common.js",
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "js", "vue", "json"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
  },
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    "<rootDir>/some-dir/**/*.(js|ts)",
  ],
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  testMatch: ["**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)", "**/*.test.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  runner: "groups",
};
```

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    …
    "test:unit": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    …
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "path-to-regexp": "^6.2.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    …
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.8",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/device": "^2.1.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.4.4",
    "jest": "^27.4.4",
    "jest-runner-groups": "^2.2.0",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.1",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bumped `core-js` to v3 and now it works. I suppose that I installed previously v2 by mistake (it [used](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6579) to be nuxt default), then updated it to v3 but forgetting `--save` flag, hence braking the versioning.

I’m leaving this question in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
I resolved it by upgrading @testing-library/react to 14.0.0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!